# Score Point System

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I watched a tutorial and is trying to do a score point system for my unity project. However, the scores are not being tabulated. I created a AddScore() function and included it in the PlayerBullet.cs (where the OnTriggerEnter2D function when there is a collision between the player bullet and enemy. The score point in the inspector window remains at 0. Can anyone help me with it? Thank you!

PlayerBullet.cs code:

```
    public int Score;

    //this function will be triggered when there is a collision between the player bullet and enemy 
    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collide)
    {
        //detects when the player's bullet collide with the enemy 
        if(collide.tag == "EnemyTag")
        {
            //destroy the player bullet 
            Destroy(gameObject);
            AddScore();
        }
    }

    void AddScore()
    {
        Score++;
    }
```

Comment: maybe you need some UI Text to show it ?

Comment: the score point in the inspector window does not increase too

Comment: print some log to console ?

Comment: maybe you never call AddScore() this function

Comment: i already called it at OnTrigger

Comment: Destroy(gameObject); this line will kill self gameobject , so addScore() maybe not called.

Comment: the `Score` variable is in the clase being destroyed. It should be made static as in the proposed answer or have a reference to an int variable from another class which is not destroyed, and have the score added to that before the destrucution

Comment: As rustyBucketBay said your goal is a bit unclear here as you destroy the gameObject this script and thereby this `Score` field belongs to .. remember that `int` is a **value** type, not a reference so if you assigned this to another classes value the change won't affect at all that other class ...

Answer (score 0):

Try this ?

```
public static int Score;

//this function will be triggered when there is a collision between the player bullet and enemy 
void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collide)
{
    //detects when the player's bullet collide with the enemy 
    if(collide.tag == "EnemyTag")
    {
        Score++;
        Debug.Log("Score: " + Score); 
        //destroy the player bullet 
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
}
```

Comment: the debug log is showed in the console. but it does not work

Comment: What is does not work mean , Is score not be more?